# Allow to disable 'Last seen at' on user profile

Tags: feature-request

There should be an option to disable 'Last seen ABC time ago', on user profile. I don't think such option yet exists.

I feel that it's somewhat against privacy.

Comment: Why does this need to be disabled?  When posting a feature, it's best to include why it should be implemented and what is the benefit of it.

Comment: @bluefeet updated request with my paranoia.

Comment: Work-around: log out from time to time.

Comment: I find it very useful to know whether someone has visited the site since a comment or and answer has been posted. Exactly what do you feel is "private" about visiting a public website?

Comment: Are you in fear about your boss could check it, and notice that you were hanging out here during working hours?  At least my plea would be _"I've done some research about this or that  problems we currently facing in our project "_ ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think my boss would be pleased to know that I signed into SO in the middle of the night. My spouse, not so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just disabling the last seen would only benefit users who don't do much activity on any of the sites, since if you do just one of many activities people will still have a decent idea about the last time you were active.

For example, if you do any review, comment, post, etc it is saved in your activity. See your activity here https://stackexchange.com/users/1366319/iosdev82?tab=activity.

So I'd say a better option to go unnoticed is to create an account that your boss/wife/etc doesn't know about so you can browse and act at your own pleasure without them being able to easily find it. But with this option they could still likely find out about it if they try a little bit and there's also chance your new account would get merged with your old account [if not careful enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-and-the-new-ui-now-live).

So in order for your feature-request to have any benefit for you you'd also have to be able to hide the activities you do on the sites. This won't probably ever be an option since the sites are community moderated and such so other users need to have access to the actions users take in order to keep the site clean and deal quickly with any problem users/actions.

Comment: I had forgotten about the activity tab. Compared to it, last seen seems like a pretty small thing. And I don't think I can convince SO to allow me to disable that. :D
I agree, creating a new account is definitely not worth it. Nor would be staying signed in while browsing, since that takes the fun away. I guess I should just be ok with it.